# Is it possible to load test classes from src/test in src/main?

Tags: java, groovy, junit, junit5

Im new in Java and JUnit technology and I cant understand why I cant create instance for class from src/test in src/main classes?

For example:

My JUnit runner is in src/main in second module(I have dependecy for first module).
JUnit runner for filtering tests required MethodSelector object but in constructor i must put Class javaClass, String methodName parameters. When I tried create instance for my test class in src/main from src/test I cant import this class...

I understand its not best practice when in src/main we create test instances but my runner must be console app so if I understand well it should be in src/main?
Over the past two weeks I have not seen another way to filter tests without class instance  and method names parameters.

I try to do it like this

```
def class = Class.forName("package.from.src.test")
```

but I always get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: You have no reason to access test classes from your main, so you should fix your design. Why is your JUnit runner in main instead of test? It's not application code, so it's in the wrong place. Test things go under `test`.

Comment: JUnit runner with other helpers is in src/main because I want create console or service app. As far as I know, you can't create widnows service or console app from the src/test path?

Comment: Junit runner should not be part of your service. It's just for running tests

Comment: tim_yates can you explain your answer why?

Comment: Because that's it's purpose... I guess you _could_ use it... Like you _could_ use a shovel for serving food... It's just not the done thing, and not the purpose it's creators cover and test for. Could you come up with a simple example of what you're trying to do? Maybe we could better advise?

Comment: ie: share a simple example of how you're trying to run your console app (doesn't have to be your actual app, but it should be complete so we can run it) it is it on GitHub/bit bucket/etc?

Comment: The convention for Java projects is to have production code in the `src/main` directory and for testing in `src/test`.  The reason you cant access `src/test` from `src/main` is likely that the class path is different for running a production build than for a test run.  Many option exist for "speeding" up testing such as running tests in parallel  or on multiple nodes, and are unlikely to require accessing test code in production code.

Comment: Thanks for fast clear response. If I decide it will be parallel execution so whats about when I will run 1000 selenium tests without headless mode? Will it succeed and won't eat a lot of memory?

Comment: What build tool are you using? Unless you need some very specific things, running your tests via e.g. gradle or maven gives you your "command line app" for tests. And it's usually easy to have separate functional tests and fire up some selenium docker container beforehand etc.

Comment: I use maven. Thank you tim_yates, Kayaman, Gavin and cfrick, its more clear now for me. In .NET its more different and I was confused but now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this very late but hoping it would help someone.

I was able to access a class from src/test into src/main using following gradle entries. I am not sure how to do it with non-gradle project.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/main/java'
            srcDirs 'src/test/java'
        }
    }
}
```